# error: conflicting types for 'x'

Tags: c, gcc, types, include

I am new to C, and I've read a number of posts trying to deal with this issue, and they all say that the error message:

```
error: conflicting types for 'x'
```

occurs because a function is used before it is declared. This is not (at least not in an obvious way) the case with my code.

I have several files in my project:

- `minty.c`
- `lexer.c`
- `lexer.h`
- `minty_util.c`
- `minty_util.h`

I compile `lexer.c` and `minty_util.c` with:

```
gcc -Wall -g -c lexer.c -o lexer.o
gcc -Wall -g -c minty_util.c -o minty_util.o
```

and these both compile successfully. The error comes when I try to compile `minty.c`:

```
gcc -Wall -g minty.c lexer.o minty_util.o -o minty
```

At which point I get about 6 errors of the form given above (where `x` is a function name) for functions declared in `minty_util.h` and defined in `minty_util.c`. From what I have read, it may have something to do with the way each file `#includes` other files, so here are the includes for each file (the obvious stuff like `stdio.h` is omitted):

- `minty.c` includes `minty_util.h` and `lexer.h`
- `lexer.c` includes `lexer.h`
- `lexer.h` includes `minty_util.h` (because it contains forward declarations using typedefs specified in `minty_util.h`)
- `minty_util.c` includes `minty_util.h`
- `minty_util.h` does not include anything

If anyone can shed any light on why I'm having this problem, it would be immensely appreciated, as I have been trying to figure this out for hours (should've posted earlier!).

Comment: Have you added `#ifndef` checks in your included files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon. The message usually means that there are two declarations for 'x', but the types of 'x' are not compatible.  So, you need to find the declarations for 'x' in all headers and C (and generated C and generated headers) to see how it is declared.  You should have a file name and line number for the problem in the error line.  If you were using a more recent version of GCC, you'd probably get better diagnostics (a second line identifying where the previous declaration appeared).  Note that showing the exact error messages is important.

Comment: Thanks, I will include this info in future posts. I'm using the gcc version currently in the repos for ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check for the header guards.It says if you include a file more than once there will be problem

look the following link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard